# Premake issues with lua

Tags: c++17, build-system, premake, build-script

I using premake as a build system and I have my Lua script but for some reason when I open my vs2022 and run it some things don't get made right. some of the projects and items have a red circle with a minus sign. and my sandbox project isn't in my directories at all.

Im using premake5-beta beta2

heres my lua script.

```
workspace "Almond"
    architecture "x64"

    configurations
    {
        "Debug",
        "Release",
        "Dist"
    }

outputdir = "%{cfg.buildcfg}-%{cfg.system}-%{cfg.architecture}"

project "Almond"
    location "Almond"
    kind "SharedLib"
    language "C++"

    targetdir ("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    objdir ("bin-int/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

    files
    {
        "%{prj.name}/src/**.h", 
        "%{prj.name}/src/**.cpp"
    }

    filter "system:windows"
        cppdialect "C++17"
        staticruntime "On"
        systemversion "latest"
        
        defines
        {
            "AM_PLATFORM_WINDOWS",
            "AM_BUILD_DLL"
        }

        postbuildcommands
        {
            ("{COPY} %{cfg.buildtarget.relpath} ../bin/" .. outputdir .. "/Sandbox")
        }
    
    filter "configurations:Debug"
        defines "AM_DEBUG"
        symbols "On"

    filter "configurations:Release"
        defines "AM_RELEASE"
        optimize "On"

    filter "configurations:Dist"
        defines "AM_DIST"
        optimize "On"

project "Sanbox"
        location "Sandbox"
        kind "ConsoleApp"
        language "C++"

        targetdir ("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
        objdir ("bin-int/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

            files
        {
            "%{prj.name}/src/**.h", 
            "%{prj.name}/src/**.cpp"
        }

        includedirs
        {
            "Almond/src"
        }

        links
        {
            "Almond"
        }

        filter "system:windows"
            cppdialect "C++17"
            staticruntime "On"
            systemversion "latest"
        
            defines
            {
            "AM_PLATFORM_WINDOWS"
            }

    filter "configurations:Debug"
        defines "AM_DEBUG"
        symbols "On"

    filter "configurations:Release"
        defines "AM_RELEASE"
        optimize "On"

    filter "configurations:Dist"
        defines "AM_DIST"
        optimize "On"
```

Ive never used premake before but ive heard its simpler than cmake for beginner. "-thecherno"

Comment: I set the startup project as sandbox and i fixed the line project "Sanbox" to "Sandbox but files still arent getting loaded right I also changed the post build command to ("{COPY} %{cfg.buildtarget.relpath} \"../bin/" .. outputdir .. "/Sandbox/\"")

Comment: `project "Sanbox"` typo? missing **d** of `sandbox`, especially as you use `prj.name` afterward.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 issues:

- typo in Sandbox project name (missing `'d'`)
- 2 issues with `postbuildcommands`:
- bin SandBox directory might not already exist, so create missing directory.
- paths in buildcommand are not really directly relative to lua script :-/

Following `postbuildcommands` should fix the issue:

```
postbuildcommands
{
    "{MKDIR} %[bin/" .. outputdir .. "/Sandbox]",
    "{COPYFILE} %[%{!cfg.buildtarget.abspath}] %[bin/" .. outputdir .. "/Sandbox]"
}
```

- `%[..]` is to make path relative to project correctly (take absolute path)
- `%{!..}` is to force path to be absolute.

Comment: Im getting a MSB3073 and a LNK1104 when I put in the new postbuild im new to premake so I dont know what these are.

Comment: Can you check in visual project that the postbuild is correct (paths). (premake got fix recently about `%[..]`, unsure if it is in beta2, or if it is for beta3). copying manually might also be a temporary test.

Comment: For my first project in the property->build events-> Post-build-event it says. IF NOT EXIST "..\bin\Debug-windows-x86_64\Sandbox" (mkdir "..\bin\Debug-windows-x86_64\Sandbox"). And when I run it the MSB3073 is linked to that.

Comment: Copy dll part seems missing...

Comment: from what part though?

Comment: Your post build event (from comment) only have `mkdir` stuff, `COPY` stuff is not present. wonder if you did some typo somewhere.

Comment: I changed abspath to rel path and I get this now. IF NOT EXIST "..\bin\Debug-windows-x86_64\Sandbox" (mkdir "..\bin\Debug-windows-x86_64\Sandbox")
copy /B /Y "..\..\bin\Debug-windows-x86_64\Almond\Almond.dll" "..\bin\Debug-windows-x86_64\Sandbox"

Comment: When i go to my bin directories no files are in sandbox or Almond

Comment: I tried to mimic your project, and I successfully build with above fixes. Having complete error message might help. You might check that paths in postbuild event are correct inside visual studio (but if you have nothing in `bin/Almond`, it already means that that project doesn't build successfully)...